# Mutable Reduction into a StringBuilder object

Tags: java, java-stream

As per the [Java Stream Package Summary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction),
*A mutable reduction operation accumulates input elements into a mutable result container, such as a Collection or **StringBuilder**, as it processes the elements in the stream.*

There are numerous examples out there for performing a mutable reduction into a Collection.  However, I cannot figure out how to realize mutable reduction operation into a StringBuilder, especially given that StringBuilder does not seem to be part of any pertinent interface definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't see [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), because the *result* of using a `StringBuilder` is a `String`. The `StringBuilder` is used behind the scenes.

*Example*

```
String[] input = { "Hell", "oW", "orld" };
String joined = Stream.of(input).collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println(joined); // prints: HelloWorld
```

If you do this without streaming, you'd do:

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : input)
    buf.append(s);
String joined = buf.toString();
```

That is also what the stream is doing. If you look at the source code of [`joining()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining--), you'll find:

```
public static Collector<CharSequence, ?, String> joining() {
    return new CollectorImpl<CharSequence, StringBuilder, String>(
            StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append,
            (r1, r2) -> { r1.append(r2); return r1; },
            StringBuilder::toString, CH_NOID);
}
```

As you can see, it also uses [`new StringBuilder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder--), [`append(CharSequence s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append-java.lang.CharSequence-), and [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#toString--).

The other two overloads, [`joining(CharSequence delimiter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) and [`joining(CharSequence delimiter, CharSequence prefix, CharSequence suffix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-), use [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) instead of `StringBuilder`.

```
public static Collector<CharSequence, ?, String> joining(CharSequence delimiter) {
    return joining(delimiter, "", "");
}

public static Collector<CharSequence, ?, String> joining(CharSequence delimiter,
                                                         CharSequence prefix,
                                                         CharSequence suffix) {
    return new CollectorImpl<>(
            () -> new StringJoiner(delimiter, prefix, suffix),
            StringJoiner::add, StringJoiner::merge,
            StringJoiner::toString, CH_NOID);
}
```